# Solving an IVP using Laplace Transformations

Tags: laplace-transform, initial-value-problems, inverse-laplace

I've been following an example from [Slader](http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780321747730-fundamentals-of-differential-equations-8th-edition/382/eercises/4/), but I can't seem to find where I'm going wrong in my own problem.

Given $y''+4y'+3y=105e^{4t}, y(0)=-4, y'(0)=25$, solve using Laplace transforms.

I start:
$$[s^2Y-sy(0)-y'(0)]+4[sY-y(0)]+3[Y]=\frac{105}{s-4}$$
$$Y[s^2+4s+3]+4s-25+4(4)=\frac{105}{s-4}$$
$$Y(s+3)(s+1)=\frac{105}{s-4}-4s+9$$
$$Y(s+3)(s+1)=\frac{105+(s-4)(-4s+9)}{s-4}$$

Isolating Y,
$$Y=\frac{105-4s^2+9s-16s-36}{(s-4)(s+1)(s+3)}$$
$$Y=\frac{-4s^2-5s+69}{(s-4)(s+1)(s+3)}$$

Then to break it up into partial fractions:
$$\frac{-4s^2-5s+69}{(s-4)(s+1)(s+3)}=\frac{A}{s-4}+\frac{B}{s+3}+\frac{C}{s+1}$$
$$-4s^2-5s+69=A(s+1)(s+3)+B(s-4)(s+1)+C(s-4)(s+3)$$

Solving for A, B, C:
$$s=4, 35A=-15, A=\frac{-3}{7}$$
$$s=-3, 14B=18, B=\frac{7}{9}$$
$$s=-1, -10C=70, C=7$$

So then I get,
$$Y=\frac{-3}{7(s-4)}+\frac{7}{9(s+3)}+\frac{7}{s+1}$$

Taking the inverse Laplace leaves me with:
$$y=\frac{-3}{7}e^{4t}+\frac{7}{9}e^{-3t}-7e^{-t}$$

Please help me, I'm on the last try before I start to lose points!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$Y=\frac{105-4s^2+9s-16s-36}{(s-4)(s+1)(s+3)}$$

Should have been

$$Y=\frac{105-4s^2+9s+16s-36}{(s-4)(s+1)(s+3)}$$